# C# - Generating a random number into a field

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to be able to be able to generate a random number e.g. WXYZ, which will be inpur into a TextBox field, at the moment I have this:

```
textBox5.Text = "<RandomNumberHere>".ToString();
```

Comment: `WXYZ` is not really a number. Some clarification would help.

Comment: @Henk It is a random number is base 36 :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just want the `Random` class.

Exploded declaration:

```
//upperLimitPlusOne is an int which is 1 + whatever you want your max number to be
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, upperLimitPlusOne);
textbox5.Text = randomNumber.ToString();
```

More condensed:

```
//same upperLimitPlusOne
Random rnd = new Random();
Textbox5.Text = (rnd.Next(0, upperLimitPlusOne)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) to generate a pseudo-random number.

```
Random random = new Random();
textBox5.Text = random.Next().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/random) that may help you use the `Random Class`. More info @ MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
textBox5.Text = new Random().Next().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you a 4-digit number with all preceding 0's

```
Random r = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
string n = r.Next(0, 10000).ToString();
textBox5.Text = "0000".Substring(0, 4 - n.Length) + n;
```